# Does IBM.WatsonDeveloperCloud.SpeechToText.v1 Support Cross Platform support in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, ibm-watson

I am working on Speech Recognition ie speech to text API in Cross-platform Xamarin forms. while doing google I found IBM.WatsonDeveloperCloud.SpeechToText.v1. So my question is does it support in Xamarin forms?
If yes, please let me know how to make it work for cross-platform architecture ie using Xamarin forms.

Comment: I saw they have .NET Standard Version of the Library https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/dotnet-standard-sdk !

Comment: @NirmalSubedi yes you are correct but it will not support in xamarin forms

Comment: It is compatible with .NetStandard 1.3, not sure why doesn't it support Xamarin.Forms? Did you try adding it?

Comment: @Shan yes I tried it but not get success.

Comment: I'm able to add it to a sample project. Any errors while adding?

Comment: do you have its sample? will you please share that with me. its more helpful for me.

Comment: @jsanalytics do you have its sample code for reference

Comment: @jsanalytics thanks for your valuable reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET SDK supports Xamarin. The support was added as part of v1.1.0.

See https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/dotnet-standard-sdk/pull/120

If you run into problems integrating IBM Watson with Xamarin feel free to open an issue in https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/dotnet-standard-sdk/issues.